# Deserializing an object with other objects in it

Tags: json, ruby, serialization, deserialization

I'm making a two-player game of chess played on the command line. I have a class for every type of chess piece and a board class. The board class looks like this:

```
class Board 
  attr_accessor :board, :choice
  def initialize
    @board = Array.new(8){Array.new(8," ")}
    @choice = choice 
  end 
end
```

My other classes look like this:

```
class Bishop
  attr_accessor :x_position, :y_position, :piece, :color, :counter, :moves
  def initialize(position,boolean) 
    @x_position = position[0]
    @y_position = position[1]
    @piece = boolean ? "♝" : "♗"
    @color = boolean ? "white" : "black"
    @counter = 0
    @moves = [[+1,-1],
    [+1,+1],
    [-1,+1],
    [-1,-1]]
  end
```

I added my pieces to the board like this:

```
@board[0][0] = Rook.new([0,0],false)
```

These are my methods to serialize and deserialize the data:

```
def to_json
  JSON.generate({board: @board})
end

def save_game(string) 
  File.open("saved.json", "w") do |game_file|
    game_file.write(string)
  end
end

def load_game
  game_file = File.read("saved.json")
  data = JSON.parse(game_file)
  @board = data["board"]
end
```

After saving, the saved.json file looks like this:

```
{"board":[[" ","#<Knight:0x00000000e4fc28>","#<Bishop:0x00000000e4fa20>","#<Queen:0x00000000e4f890>","#<King:0x00000000e4f610>","#<Bishop:0x00000000e4f3e0>","#<Knight:0x00000000e4f278>","#<Rook:0x00000000e4e1c0>"],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],["#<Rook:0x00000000e4fd90>","#<Knight:0x00000000e4ed78>","#<Bishop:0x00000000e4eb70>","#<Queen:0x00000000e4ea08>","#<King:0x00000000e4e7b0>","#<Bishop:0x00000000e4e580>","#<Knight:0x00000000e4e3f0>"," "]]}
```

When I try to load back the data, the method that displays the board throws this error:

```
 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
 +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
0|    /home/jacob/Desktop/chess/board.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in display': undefined method `piece' for "#<Knight:0x00000000e4fc28>":String (NoMethodError)
    from /home/jacob/Desktop/chess/board.rb:27:in `each'
    from /home/jacob/Desktop/chess/board.rb:27:in `each_with_index'
    from /home/jacob/Desktop/chess/board.rb:27:in `block in display'
    from /home/jacob/Desktop/chess/board.rb:20:in `each'
    from /home/jacob/Desktop/chess/board.rb:20:in `each_with_index'
```

It looks like my problem is that the objects come back as strings?

my display method:

```
 def display
    axis = 0
    print "   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7"
    @board.each_with_index do |row,index|
      print "\n"
      @draw = " +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+"
      puts @draw
      print axis
      axis +=1
      if index.even?
        row.each_with_index do|column,i|
          if i.odd?
            if column != " "
              print "|"+" #{column.piece}  ".bruno
            else  print "|"+" #{column}  ".bruno
            end
          else
            if column != " "
              print "|"+" #{column.piece}  "
            else  print "|"+" #{column}  "
            end
          end 
        end
      else
        row.each_with_index do|column,j|
          if j.even?
            if column != " "
              print "|"+" #{column.piece}  ".bruno
            else  print "|"+" #{column}  ".bruno
            end
          else   
            if column != " "
              print "|"+" #{column.piece}  "
            else  print "|"+" #{column}  "
            end
          end
        end
      end
      print "|"
    end 
    print "\n"
    print @draw
  end
```

Comment: Which part belongs to which file? We can't follow the backtrace without it. And there isn't any place in what you have shown that calls `piece`, which is the cause of the error.

Comment: Piece is an instance in every type of pieces class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the problem is that your objects are **saved** as strings. Deserialization works fine, in this case. You'll have to explicitly specify what should be the json representation of your game pieces. Something like this:

```
class Rook
  def to_json(*)
    { name: 'rook', position: 'A1', status: 'in_game' }.to_json
  end
end

pieces = [Rook.new]
pieces.to_json # => "[{\"name\":\"rook\",\"position\":\"A1\",\"status\":\"in_game\"}]"
JSON.parse(pieces.to_json) # => [{"name"=>"rook", "position"=>"A1", "status"=>"in_game"}]
```

On deserialization you'll have to do the reverse. Construct proper game classes from plain ruby hashes, which you get from parsing JSON file.

Or if you don't actually care about JSON and just want to create *some* form of save file, then `Marshal` is your best friend. No need to override anything. Zero friction.

```
pieces = [Rook.new]
Marshal.dump(pieces) # => "\x04\b[\x06o:\tRook\x00" # write this to a file
# restore it later
Marshal.load("\x04\b[\x06o:\tRook\x00") # => [#<Rook:0x007fb50f825570>]
```